# How to Increment Version Number via Gulp Task?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, build-process

I would like to replace a string indicating version number in a javascript file (`myConstantsFile.js`), with another string. So, for example, my version number looks like this: "01.11.15", written like this in `myConstantsFile.js`  with other constants:

```
.constant('productVersion', '1.11.15');
```

Right now, my task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('increment-version', function(){
    gulp.src(['./somedir/myConstantsFile.js'])
        .pipe(replace(/'productVersion', '(.*)'/g, '99.99.99'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./somedir/'));
});
```

As you can see, I am using a constant, not running [incrementation code](https://plnkr.co/edit/zsUG3DcQNyBPsMRY1avD?p=preview), which would look like this:

```
    var numberString = '0.0.1';
    var versionParts = numberString.split('.');
    var vArray = {
      vMajor : versionParts[0],
      vMinor : versionParts[1],
      vPatch : versionParts[2]
    } 

    vArray.vPatch = parseFloat(vArray.vPatch) + 1;
    var periodString = ".";

    var newVersionNumberString = vArray.vMajor + periodString + 
                                vArray.vMinor+ periodString + 
                                vArray.vPatch;
```

I need:

1. A way to select the current version number via regex via the file.
2. To know where I can put the logic in the last code block to increment the number and build the new string.

Comment: What about gulp-bump ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bump

Comment: From past experience, keep your build number in its own file (in this case, maybe even JSON). When sed replacements in a code file eventually cause a problem, it will be damn near impossible to figure out.

Comment: @cl3m Looks good, I am looking over the functionality. My main problems are the basic selection of the data via regex to work with and where to put my vars/functions. This is my first time doing anything with gulp, other than running browser-sync and such. ssube - that's a good idea, but the problem is that angular constants need to pull from it.

Comment: we do a very similar thing with grunt. version is stored on package.json, and increment in a grunt task file. *Not sure how this translates to Gulp.* I will say that this has proved somewhat fragile because multiple developers can each perform an increment on a build, and because package.json is not (in our case) version controlled, it can easily get out of sync. So - the takeaway is : version control your build number source.

Comment: @Bosworth99 Noted. This whole thing is a pain, we increment version number in SQL during the build as well, but not via gulp, then check if versions line up to see if user refreshed browser after update (in case API calls changed or something). I am yet to see a proper way to do it, but that's a different question altogether.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Install [gulp-bump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bump)

```
npm install gulp-bump --save-dev
```

Install [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)

```
npm install yargs --save-dev
```

Require gulp-bump

```
var bump = require('gulp-bump');
```

Require yargs

```
var args = require('yargs').argv;
```

Your bump task

```
gulp.task('bump', function () {
    /// <summary>
    /// It bumps revisions
    /// Usage:
    /// 1. gulp bump : bumps the package.json and bower.json to the next minor revision.
    ///   i.e. from 0.1.1 to 0.1.2
    /// 2. gulp bump --version 1.1.1 : bumps/sets the package.json and bower.json to the 
    ///    specified revision.
    /// 3. gulp bump --type major       : bumps 1.0.0 
    ///    gulp bump --type minor       : bumps 0.1.0
    ///    gulp bump --type patch       : bumps 0.0.2
    ///    gulp bump --type prerelease  : bumps 0.0.1-2
    /// </summary>

    var type = args.type;
    var version = args.version;
    var options = {};
    if (version) {
        options.version = version;
        msg += ' to ' + version;
    } else {
        options.type = type;
        msg += ' for a ' + type;
    }


    return gulp
        .src(['Path to your package.json', 'path to your bower.json'])
        .pipe(bump(options))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('path to your root directory'));
});
```

---

VSO Note: I believe a lot of people coming to this thread will be looking exactly for the answer above. The code below is to edit a version number stored somewhere BESIDES the npm/bower package files, such as in angular constants:

```
gulp.task('increment-version', function(){
    //docString is the file from which you will get your constant string
    var docString = fs.readFileSync('./someFolder/constants.js', 'utf8');

    //The code below gets your semantic v# from docString
    var versionNumPattern=/'someTextPreceedingVNumber', '(.*)'/; //This is just a regEx with a capture group for version number
    var vNumRexEx = new RegExp(versionNumPattern);
    var oldVersionNumber = (vNumRexEx.exec(docString))[1]; //This gets the captured group

    //...Split the version number string into elements so you can bump the one you want
    var versionParts = oldVersionNumber.split('.');
    var vArray = {
        vMajor : versionParts[0],
        vMinor : versionParts[1],
        vPatch : versionParts[2]
    };

    vArray.vPatch = parseFloat(vArray.vPatch) + 1;
    var periodString = ".";

    var newVersionNumber = vArray.vMajor + periodString +
                           vArray.vMinor+ periodString +
                           vArray.vPatch;

    gulp.src(['./someFolder/constants.js'])
        .pipe(replace(/'someTextPreceedingVNumber', '(.*)'/g, newVersionNumber))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./someFolder/'));
});
```

I ommitted some mumbo-jumbo that writes my constant in a pretty string, but that's the gist and it works.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, upvoted, and will probably end up accepting and asking another question, but I am not looking to bump package.json, I am looking to change a string in a different file. Maybe I am misunderstanding the limitations of gulp.

Comment: Gulp is pretty awesome. Expect anything. You may want to look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36335869/4775223

Comment: Thanks - is there some easy way to get the result of my regex - /'productVersion', '(.*)'/g into a var and then work on it? Or does that end up being a plugin?

Comment: Here is an idea. Since your package.json is yours, maybe you can have gulp-replace use the package.json version to update your string somewhere else, and still use bump to control your versions. Is not that round about. It would mean adding a pipe to the bump task.

Comment: To your last question, maybe this will work: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29770191/4775223

Comment: Thanks, looking through the solutions now. If that works, I might add it to the bottom of your answer before accepting, if you don't mind. The first one is a good idea, but I would rather not go through the package file if I can help it simply because it seems convoluted, though in practice it probably is simpler than what I am trying to do.

Comment: Good point. Feel free to edit and add value to the post. I look forward to seeing what you end up with.

Comment: I added some stuff, feel free to edit as well if you would like. It's your answer, and it definitely helped a ton.

Comment: ReferenceError: fs is not defined also ReferenceError: msg is not defined

Answer (score 4):

Started looking into gulp since past 5 hours,as I had a task to fix the requirement. So, being a definite noob to gulp I came out with the below code which is **without the regex expression**. Thanks to *@VSO* and *@Wilmer Saint* for a quick start. Might be a tiny change, but this helped me.

```
gulp.task('version', function(){
  var fs = require('fs');
    //docString is the file from which you will get your constant string
    var docString = fs.readFileSync('app/scripts/version/version.js', 'utf8'); //type of docString i an object here.

    var versionParts = docString.split('.');

    var vArray = {
        vMajor : versionParts[0],
        vMinor : versionParts[1],
        vPatch : versionParts[2]
    };

    vArray.vPatch = parseFloat(vArray.vPatch) + 1;
    var periodString = ".";
    var newVersionNumber = vArray.vMajor + periodString +
                           vArray.vMinor+ periodString +
                           vArray.vPatch;



    require('fs').writeFileSync('app/scripts/version/version.js', newVersionNumber + "'");
        return gulp.src(['app/scripts/version/version.js'])
            .pipe(gulp.dest('app/scripts/version/new_version'));//creates version.js file in the directory
    });
```

or the return code could be as below to override the number in version.js file

```
return gulp.src(['app/scripts/version/version.js'],
                {base: './app/scripts/version/version.js'})
        .pipe((gulp.dest('./app/scripts/version/version.js')))
```

My version.js has only below code

```
versionBuild = '1.0.8'
```

I used the below in my main function(loads on loading the app)

```
var versionBuild=parseInt(1000*Math.random());
var random = function(digs){
    var rndn;
    if(window.location.hostname === "localhost" || window.location.hostname === "127.0.0.1") {
        rndn = Math.random();
        if(digs != undefined && !isNaN(digs)){
              rndn =  parseInt(Math.pow(10, digs)*rndn)
              }
              return rndn;
    }
    else {
        return versionBuild;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use gulp-bump, it's very easy and sweet :)

> ```
> npm install --save gulp-bump
> ```

```
const bump = require('gulp-bump');

gulp.task('bump', async () => {
    gulp.src('./package.json')
    .pipe(bump({key: "version"}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
  });
```

> Note: use `async` before a function. it's a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('bump', function() {
    var vers = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/package.json')).version.split('.');
    var second = parseInt(vers[1]);
    var third  = parseInt(vers[2]);
    var options = { key: 'version' };

    if(third == 9 && second != 9) {
        third = 0;
        options.type = 'minor';
    } else if (second == 9 && third == 9) {
        second = 0;
        options.type = 'major';
    }

    gulp.src(__dirname + '/package.json')
    .pipe(bump(options))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: I think there's no need