# Update version number stored in json file

Tags: json, shell, scripting, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to write a shell script to increment a build number of a version stored in a JSON file.

```
{
  /**
   * The application's namespace.
   */
  "name": "AppName",

  /**
   * The version of the application.
   */
  "version": "1.0.0.23",

  /**
   * More comments.....
   */
  ....
}
```

I've already tested a simple way to increment the number if the variable was already in the file:

```
version='1.0.0.23'
a=( ${version//./ } )                   # replace points, split into array
((a[3]++))                              # increment revision (or other part)
version="${a[0]}.${a[1]}.${a[2]}.${a[3]}"       # compose new version
echo $version                                   # outputs: 1.0.0.24
```

I've looked at jq and jshon but neither will parse the JSON file because it contains comments (the app.json file is generated automatically by Sencha Cmd)

How can I read the version property using something like awk / sed and update it? Would jsawk be better?

**Update**
I've managed to extract the version number using this:
`version=$( sed -n 's/.*"version": "\(.*\)",/\1/p' app2.json )`
so now I can read the version and increment it. Just need to write it back now.

Comment: Isn't there an option to omit the comments? Can't believe that a tool produces `*.json` files which aren't valid json.

Comment: seems to be the Sencha standard: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/microloader.html

Comment: Hmm, I've no idea about sencha. I've added the tag sencha. It's more likely that you'll find somebody who knows then.

Comment: This question has been answered before in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36340305/4775223. This answer has two parts

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'["]' -v OFS='"'  '/"version":/{
    split($4,a,".");
    $4=a[1]"."a[2]"."a[3]"."a[4]+1
    }
;1' app.json
```

with `IFS` and `OFS` as `"` find line that matches `"version":`.

`split($4,a,".")` : `split` the fourth field with `.` as separator and save to array `a`.

`$4=a[1]"."a[2]"."a[3]"."a[4]+1` : Reassign the `$4` with new value.

`1` : print all the lines

If input line is `"version": "1.0.0.23",`

O/P will be `"version": "1.0.0.24",`

Comment: Specify file at the end of awk command. Avoid [Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).

Answer (score 3):

I continued experimenting with sed and managed to produce this:

```
# get the existing version number
ver=$( sed -n 's/.*"version": "\(.*\)",/\1/p' app2.json )    # ver='1.0.0.43'
echo "Current version: $ver"

a=( ${ver//./ } )                           # replace points, split into array
((a[3]++))                                 # increment revision (or other part)
newVer="${a[0]}.${a[1]}.${a[2]}.${a[3]}"   # compose new version
echo "New version: $newVer"                 # newVer='1.0.0.44'

# write output
sed -i .temp "s/\"version\": \"$ver\"/\"version\": \"$newVer\"/g" app2.json
```

which does the job.

Comment: I used parameter expansion

`v=$(cat package.json | grep -m 1 version | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g')` // v = 1.10.210

`p=${v##*.}` // p = 210

`uP=$((p+1))` // uP = 211

`sed -i '' 's/\"version\": \"'$v'\"/\"version\": \"'$mV'\"/g' package*.json; git checkout -b hotfix/$mV;` // change both package.json and package-lock.json. and I used this in git alias so double quotes and quotes are confusingly mixed

Answer (score 3):

Building off of 7171u's answer, here is a complete one-liner that overwrites the original json file with the patch incremented version:

```
awk -F'["]' -v OFS='"'  '/"version":/{split($4,a,".");$4=a[1]"."a[2]"."a[3]+1};1' ./manifest.json > ./manifest2.json && mv ./manifest2.json ./manifest.json
```

This will get the current version from the json file, increment the patch version position, write it out to a new file, then in the second statement, replace the original file with the new one.