# How to inject a comment in javascript files using gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, code-injection

I try to add a header to every js-file in my project.

The current files are without comments in header.
I want a gulp-task to insert following header to the files:

```html
/*
 * New Comment from Gulp-Task
 */
```

Is there a plugin, already ?
Gulp-Inject is maybe the solution, but I don´t know, how to use it for javascript injection.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the solution that work for me:

```
gulp.src(['./**/*.js'])
    .pipe(insert.prepend(license))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
```

It prepend a license head to every .js files in this directory and sub folders.

Comment: explain it to new programmers. where does `insert` and `license` come from?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a straight answer to your question as it requires some translation to your case, but here is a post on how to update version numbers (in your case, something else) within javascript files.

[How to Increment Version Number via Gulp Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339694/how-to-increment-version-number-via-gulp-task/36340305#36340305)

The second part to this answer is where you'll find your clue.

Comment: okay, that was a basic approach. But I think, I needn´t to replace but add something in head.

Comment: Okay I found a package, called gulp-insert. Thereby it is possible to add a header =)